# Simple Hangman game in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hangman

I recently started learning Python, and made a simple text based Hangman game. I wanted to know if there could be anything done to make the code cleaner or more efficient.

```
import random
import os
import sys

def main():
    pickword()

def start(word, twoplayer):
    wordarray = ''
    userguess = []
    guessright = 0
    lettersright = 0
    if len(word) < 5:
        tries = 6
    else:
        tries = 10
    usedletters = []

    if twoplayer == False:
        print(word)
        print("Welcome to hangman")
        print("I will think of a word and you will have to guess it, are you ready!")
        input("Press enter to continue")
    else:
        print("Welcome to hangman")
        print("Player 1 has already thought of a word, let's begin")
        input("Press enter to continue")

    lengthword = len(word)

    if twoplayer == False:
        for i in range(1, lengthword):                  #creates a new variable, all underscores
            userguess.append("_ ")
    else:
         for i in range(1, lengthword):                  #creates a new variable, all underscores
            userguess.append("_ ")



    wordarray = (list(word))

    if twoplayer == False:
        for i in range(0, lengthword):                  #removes \n from end of word
            if wordarray[i] == "\n":
                wordarray.remove(wordarray[i])
                break

    usedletters = []
    getuserguess(wordarray, userguess, tries, usedletters, word)

def pickword():
    word = 0
    twoplayer = input("Do you want to play 2 player[Y/N]")
    if twoplayer.lower() == "y":
        word = input("Player 1, enter the word you want player 2 to guess, don't let them see! ")

        if len(word) < 3:
            print("That word is too short")
            pickword()

        print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")
        print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")
        print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")

        word = word.lower()
        twoplayer = True
        start(word, twoplayer)
    else:
        try:
            word = random.choice(open('hangman.txt').readlines())
            twoplayer = False
            start(word, twoplayer)

        except:
            input("Error, no word list found, press enter to exit")
            sys.exit()



def getuserguess(wordarray, userguess, tries, usedletters, word):

    print(' '.join(userguess))
    guess1 = input("Enter your guess: ")

    if len(guess1) < 1 or len(guess1) > 1 or guess1.isdigit():
        print("Invalid input")
        getuserguess(wordarray, userguess, tries, usedletters, word)
    else:
        checkuserguess(wordarray, userguess, guess1, usedletters, tries, word)



def lose(word):
    again = input("Sorry, you lost, the word was {}Would you like to play again[Y/N]".format(word))
    if again.lower() ==  "y":
        pickword()
    else:
        sys.exit()

def win():
    again = input("Congrats, you won hangman, do you want to play again?[Y/N]")
    if again == "Y" or "y":
        pickword()
    else:
        sys.exit()

def checkuserguess(wordarray, userguess, guess1, usedletters, tries, word):

    guess1list = (list(guess1))

    if guess1list[0] in usedletters:
        print("You already used that letter")
        getuserguess(wordarray, userguess, tries, usedletters, word)

    if guess1 in wordarray:
        usedletters.append(guess1)
        for i in range(0, len(wordarray)):
            if wordarray[i] == guess1list[0]:
                userguess[i] = guess1list[0]
                usedletters.append(guess1list[0])

        if "_ " not in userguess:
            print(' '.join(userguess))
            win()
        else:
            getuserguess(wordarray, userguess, tries, usedletters, word)

    else:
        if tries > 0:
            print("Sorry, that letter is not in the word, you have ", tries, " remaining")
            tries -= 1
            getuserguess(wordarray, userguess, tries, usedletters, word)
        else:
            lose(word)





main()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this, I am going to go through your program in the order it is written:

- Don't use `if twoplayer == False:`.  You can simply say `if not twoplayer:`  You don't even need that, though the first time because you do the same thing in the `if` and `else`blocks`.
- You can use `" ".join("_" * lengthword)` instead of  `for i in range(1, lengthword): userguess.append("_ ")`.  Besides making it cleaner, you weren't adding enough underscores.  The second argument to `range()` is exclusive.  Imagine if the length of the word is two.  In that case, `range(1, 2)` returns `[1]` because the second argument is exclusive.  That has length 1 instead of the same length as the word: 2.
- Don't use `wordarray.remove(wordarray[i])`.  Instead, use `wordarray.pop(i)`.  If you use `.remove()`, the first occurrence of the word will be removed, not necessarily the one you want to be removed.
- When you ask `"Do you want to play 2 player?"`, you account for `"y"` and anything else.  What if the user says `"yes"`?  It would still count as no.  Instead, you should use a `while` loop:

  ```
  twoplayer = input("Do you want to play 2 player? [Y/N] ")
  while twoplayer.lower() not in ("y", "n"):
      twoplayer = input("[Y/N] ")
  ```
- Instead of setting `twoplayer` inside of the `if` and `else` blocks, you can just do `twoplayer = ("n", "y").index(twoplayer.lower())`
- If the word is too short, you don't want to call `pickword()` again because `pickword()` asks `"Do you want to play 2 player?"`  If the word is too short, that doesn't mean the user wants to change his mind on that question.  Instead, use a loop:

  ```
  while len(word) < 3:
      print("That word is too short")
      word = input("Player 1, enter the word you want player 2 to guess, don't let them see! ")
  ```
- How do you know how many lines to print?  Instead of printing an arbitrary number of lines, `print("\033c")` will clear the terminal.
- You call `start(word, twoplayer)` in both the `if` and the `else` block.  That is a sign that it shouldn't be in either one.  Put it after both blocks so that you aren't duplicating code.
- While we're at that point in the program, you want only one line in your `try:` block: `word = random.choice(...)`.  `twoplayer` should be defined as I outlined above, so we don't need that here at all and `start(word, twoplayer)` will be outside of the `if` and `else` blocks, so we don't need that.  Besides, the only reason you want the `try` block is because you are dealing with a file.  If anything else is throwing an error, you *want* the traceback because it shouldn't be.
- Don't use a bare `except:`  You have certain errors that you think you might get; list them here.  In this case, it's `except IOError:`
- `sys.exit()`, when given an argument, uses that argument as the exit code.  In this case it is failure, so you should use `sys.exit(1)`.
- Your check for `guess1`'s validity is not the best.  To make sure that it is one character, use `len(guess1) != 1` as the check.  Also, `guess1.isdigit()` is probably not the only thing that is invalid.  For example, `$` shouldn't be in the word, right?  Instead, use `not guess1.isalpha()` to make sure it is an alphabetic character.
- Instead of using recursion and typing out all of those variable names, use a loop:

  ```
  print(' '.join(userguess))
  guess = input("Enter your guess: ")
  while len(guess) != 1 or not guess.isalpha():
      print("Invalid input")
      guess = input("Try again: ")

  checkuserguess(wordarray, userguess, guess, usedletters, tries, word)
  ```
- You have duplicate code in `lose()` and `win()`: `Would you like to play again`.  Instead, define a function that asks that question, and use it in `lose()` and `win()`.  Make sure that in that function you use `if again.lower() == "y":` as you did in `lose()`.  `if again == "Y" or "y":` does not work how you would expect it to.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values) StackOverflow post for why.
- You check if `"_ "` is in `userguess`, but you should be checking for just the underscore, not the underscore with a space.  If the underscore is at the end of the word, there shouldn't be a space.  If there is, you're doing it wrong and you shouldn't depend on it.

This is my first complete review, so if anyone has suggestions, I would be happy to modify it.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I understand everything except the part where you say use twoplayer = ("n", "y").index(twoplayer.lower()). Could you explain this a little bit more.

Comment: `twoplayer.lower()` will be either `"y"` or `"n"`.  If it is `"y"`, then `("n", "y").index(twoplayer.lower())` will be 1.  If it is `"n"`, then it will be 0.  Since 1 has a boolean value of `True` and 0 has a boolean value of `False`, `twoplayer` can now be used as a boolean.

Comment: One more thing, could you please explain how I should use " ".join("_" * lengthword)

Comment: You can take out the `for` loop and put that in.  I edited my answer to make that more clear and to add one more thing on that.

Comment: Might just make it that little clearer for twoplayer = ("n", "y").index(twoplayer.lower()) to use twoplayer = bool(("n", "y").index(twoplayer.lower())) to make it explicit that the index will be a boolean value?  Great work @zondo !